# Trapezoidal and Simpsons rule Error Analysis

Tags: calculus, error-function

[image]

I was hoping someone could help me understand how to find the upper bound of the second derivative of the function above so I could use it in analyzing the error in the trapezoidal or Simpsons rule.

Comment: I believe you can find the second derivative of $\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$. Then analyze its behavior for $0 \le x \le 1$. What you can conclude about monotonicity on given interval?